# Python read a single unicode character from the user

Tags: python, unicode, stdin

I am searching for a method to get a single **unicode** character from the standard input.  Recently, I saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) in which the solution does not apply for unicode characters but only ASCII ones.

Using the function `getch()` cited in the mentioned topic, when the user types an unicode character, it is represented as more than one ASCII characters. In fact, `getch()` only returns the first part (byte).  The remaining bytes are only accessible using `getch()` again (however I do not know how to know how many bytes remain).

Is there a way to actually get a single unicode character from the input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) the first byte of a multibyte character tells you how many bytes there are. So something like this can work:

```py
c = getch()
first_byte = ord(c)
bytes_remain = 0
while (first_byte >> (6 - bytes_remain)) & 0b11 == 0b11:
    bytes_remain += 1
    c += getch()
```